# Multiplicar coluna com count() de ManyToMany da mesma Model Django

Tags: python, django, orm

Tenho uma model chamada `Notificacoes` e ela tem a seguinte estrutura:

```
Notificacoes(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    users_interacting = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="u_interacting", null=True, blank=True)
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ....
```

Quando um usuario recebe uma notificacao, eu crio um registro nessa Model, sendo user o usuario que recebeu a notificacao e users_interacting os usuarios que estão interagindo com o user nessa notificacao.

Dessa forma, eu aproveito a mesma notificacao e apenas adiciono usuarios que estao interagindo.

O problema está no `score`, eu faco um Sum de scores a cada `save` dessa model, pois cada tipo de notificacao tem um score:

```
score = Notificacoes.objects.filter(user = self.user).aggregate(Sum('score'))['score__sum']
```

Ele me retorna a soma de todos os scores para aquele usuario. Porém, as vezes em **um registro** eu posso ter o **score 5** para aquele tipo de notificacao porem no **users_interacting tem 30 usuarios** que participam daquela notificação. Então no caso, **o valor do score deveria ser é 5 * 30** porém ele **contabiliza o apenas 5** porque é apenas uma notificação.

> Como posso multiplicar o `score` com o `users_interacting.count()` do
>   mesmo registro da model?

Exemplo:

```
notificacao_id | score | users_interacting
------------------------------------------
       1       |   5   |         1
------------------------------------------
       2       |  10   |         5
```

O sum que eu faço retorna -> **score = 5 + 10 = 15**.

O que eu gostaria de rotornar -> **score = (5 * 1) + (10 * 5) = 55.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tudo que você precisa é de uma função que realiza a soma ponderada dos `scores`. Diferentemente do que pensei inicialmente, essa função precisa ser um método aceito no `aggregate`, então funções externas não resolvem o problema. Eu pesquisei um pouco e descobri que para realizar uma soma ponderada dentro do `aggregate`, você precisa passar um objeto que é o produto escalar de dois vetores. Tente essa solução:

```
score = Notificacoes.objects.all().annotate(
    total_weight=ExpressionWrapper(F('score') * F('users_interacting'), 
                                   output_field=IntegerField() ))

score.aggregate(total=Sum('total_weight'))
```

Comment: Mas no caso, como eu faria isso usando a ORM do Django? Atualmente estou fazendo um for nas notificações e fazendo a multiplicação na mão, (está funcionando), mas acredito que exista uma forma mais performática. Usando a ORM do Django eu não tenho acesso ao total de `users_interacting`.

Comment: Ah sim. Eu achei que `sum` que você tinha usado era a `built-in` do python, assim, bastava trocar a função. Vou editar minha resposta. Um minuto

Comment: @GuilhermeIA veja agora

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado!